# Hadoop multiple datanodes on single machine

Tags: hadoop

I'm interested in configuring multiple data nodes (say 2) on a single Linux machine.

I made some research and followed a tutorial but didn't work.

If someone can give a working tutorial or show me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: you can configure only one datanode per one machine.
you can configure multiple data nodes with the help of VM's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating separate VM's you can run multiple datanode instance in the same node itself. Only thing is you got to maintain different configurations for each datanode instance.

Need to specify different port for each datanode daemons
override the following parameters in [hdfs-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml):

```
dfs.datanode.address  0.0.0.0:50010  The datanode server address and port for data transfer.
dfs.datanode.http.address    0.0.0.0:50075  The datanode http server address and port.
dfs.datanode.ipc.address     0.0.0.0:50020  The datanode ipc server address and port.
```

Also need to maintain different data directory for each datanode daemons 
override the following parameters

```
dfs.datanode.data.dir
```

Comment: Can you please give me more details, where should I overwrite these parameters? They should be in XML representation? Thank you

Comment: Where is the details of maintaining & pointing to two different hdfs-sile.xml?

Comment: What about installing on the same machine two datanodes which belong to two different HDFS?