# hadoop - Multiple datanode configuration in Pseudo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, datanode

I am newbie in hadoop. I have setup hadoop - Pseudo-distributed mode in single machine. My hdfs-site.xml configuration as default:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

After run:

> hdfs namenode -format
>   start-all.sh
>   jps

I have one namenode and one datanode.
I want to have multiple datanode on this machine and I try to config at this advice: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401159/hadoop-multiple-datanodes-on-single-machine) and my config:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode-1</value>
    <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:9870</value>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:9090</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode-2</value>
    <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:9871</value>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:9091</value>
</property>
```

And I gain zero datanode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key part of that linked answer is **you got to maintain different configurations for each datanode instance**

You cannot put two `<name>` and `<value>` sections as part of the **same** XML file

You are required to have two separate config files, one for each datanode.
 However, I
m not completely sure it is possible to have two `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` variables for unique Hadoop processes. There might be a way to do `hadoop --config /some/path datanode`, but `start-dfs` is just hiding that way to run a datanode away  from you

That being said, assuming you have `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop` and `ls $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hdfs-site.xml` is working, then you can try the following in its own terminal

```sh
mkdir /etc/hadoop2
cp /etc/hadoop/* /etc/hadoop2/

# EDIT the new hdfs-site.xml file

hadoop --config /etc/hadoop2 datanode
```

I would recommend just using two separate virtual machines, because that'll more closely match a real-world scenario

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, can you give me more detail or any tutorial?

Comment: What are you planning to gain from running more than one datanode? You are on a single machine already, so replication doesnt do anything

Comment: Yes but I want to  test distributed feature, datanode behavior and how namenode store its metadata, fsimage ...

Comment: Nothing is "distributed" until you cross over a non-local network interface. And the FSImage still works with one datanode

Comment: How about this tutor: (https://bigdata.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/hadoop-cookbook-4-how-to-run-multiple-data-nodes-on-one-machine/)

Comment: VMs are great for simulations, however, I already added everything you need in my answer